# Line Integral: why does it require |r'(t)|?

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

I'm a confused by the following definition of the line integral from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition):

For some scalar field $f : U \subset R^n \to R$ the line integral
along some piecewise curve $C \subset U$ is defined as:   $\int_C f(r) \ ds = \int_a^b f(r(t)) | r'(t) | dt$

where $r : [a,b] \to C$ is an arbitrary bijective parametrization
of the curve $C$ such that $r(a)$ and $r(b)$ give endpoints of $C$.

**QUESTIONS**

On the LHS $r$ is used.  Is it still defined as a bijective parametrization?

On the RHS why is the Euclidean norm $|r'(t)|$ required in the equation?  Intuitively, it seems the line integral could just be calculated $\int_a^b f(r(t)) dt$?

Comment: You have wrong symbols all over here. Why a $>$ in the middle of the line integral? For a mapping, you use $\to$, not $\implies$. The $r$ should not be on the left; it should be a neutral letter like $x$. $s$ represents arclength on the curve; do you think that if you change $t$ a little, then $r(t)$ moves a distance of $\Delta t$? When you drive your car, is your distance given by the time you drive, independent of your speed?

Comment: Fixed. Quoting caused it.

Comment: In the same wiki, if you scroll a little down, they tell you why you have to multiply by $|r'|.$ What is unclear there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factor makes the integral well-defined, meaning that it doesn’t depend on the choice of parametrization of the curve.

See the below answer of @Doug M for an example.

> Suppose you have your parametrization of $x$ and $y$ in terms of some parameter t.  We could replace $t$ with $2t$ and it would still describe the same curve.  You would be moving along the curve at twice the speed, but it is the same curve.  As a result of moving along that curve at twice the speed, the interval of integration will be cut in half though.  The $|r'(t)|$ will correct for such shenanigans.
>
> $\int_a^b f(r(t))|r'(t)|\ dt = \int_{\frac {a}{2}}^{\frac {b}{2}}
> > f(r(2t))|r'(2t)|\ dt$
>
> We want to analyze the integrand such that ever piece of the curve of
> equal length has equal contribution regardless of the "speed" we are
> moving across those lengths.
>
> The $|r'(t)|$ factor gives us a consistent integral for a path
> regardless of the parameterization of that path.

Comment: Your answer shouldn't rely on the presence of a comment (which can vanish without a trace); if you need to refer to the comment, you probably should quote it.

Answer (score 2):

A stupid example of why you need the $|r'(t)|$ factor.

Suppose you have your parametrization of $x$ and $y$ in terms of some parameter t.  We could replace $t$ with $2t$ and it would still describe the same curve.  You would be moving along the curve at twice the speed, but it is the same curve.  As a result of moving along that curve at twice the speed, the interval of integration will be cut in half though.  The $|r'(t)|$ will correct for such shenanigans.

$\int_a^b f(r(t))|r'(t)|\ dt = \int_{\frac {a}{2}}^{\frac {b}{2}} f(r(2t))|r'(2t)|\ dt$

We want to analyze the integrand such that ever piece of the curve of equal length has equal contribution regardless of the "speed" we are moving across those lengths.

The $|r'(t)|$ factor gives us a consistent integral for a path regardless of the parameterization of that path.